# only highlight "*", not the entire heading line in org-mode, emacs

Tags: emacs, themes, org-mode

How can I only highlight the * star, not the entire heading line, to keep texts in same color? In the great emacs org-mode

thanks guys

---

excample (replace * by #, for cann't bold * in stack-overflow)

(not below)

**# heading text**

*this is text body*

(but below)

**#** *heading text*

*this is text body*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

See the variable `org-level-color-stars-only`, which contains a doc-string that states:  "*Non-nil means fontify only the stars in each headline.  When nil, the entire headline is fontified.  Changing it requires restart of `font-lock-mode' to become effective also in regions already fontified.*"

USAGE:  `(setq org-level-color-stars-only t)`

---

**Previous Answer**

You can remove or add stars as you see fit -- this example uses two (2) stars together.  If you do just one star, then that would also affect two (2) and three (3) stars together.  Maybe one of our forum local regexp experts could please give us the code for one star (*but not more than one star*)  :)

```
(defvar bumble-bee (make-face 'bumble-bee))

(set-face-attribute 'bumble-bee nil :background "black" :foreground "yellow")

(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode (list

    (list (concat "\\*\\*")
        '(0 bumble-bee t))

   ))
```

These control the title of tasks -- you could set them all the same or make them different.  Anything you don't want, just set to `nil` or set to the same color as whatever your regular font is.

```
(custom-set-faces

  '(org-level-1 ((t (:foreground "orange" :bold t))))

  '(org-level-2 ((t (:foreground "black" :bold t))))

  '(org-level-3 ((t (:foreground "pink" :bold t))))

  '(org-level-4 ((t (:foreground "cyan" :bold t))))

  )
```

The other components of the first line are usually:  `org-tag`; `org-tag-faces`; `org-todo-keyword-faces`; `org-priority-faces`; and `org-warning`:

```
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces '(
  ("Active" . (:foreground "red"))
  ("Next Action" . (:foreground "ForestGreen"))
  ("Reference" . (:foreground "purple"))
  ("Someday" . (:foreground "gray65"))
  ("None" . (:foreground "green"))
  ("Delegated" . (:foreground "cyan")) ))

(setq org-tag-faces '(
  ("TODO" . org-warning)
  ))

(setq org-priority-faces '(
  (?A . (:foreground "firebrick" :weight bold))
  (?B . (:foreground "orange"))
  (?C . (:foreground "green"))
  (?D . (:foreground "purple"))
  (?E . (:foreground "blue")) ))

(custom-set-faces
  '(org-tag ((t (:background "gray97" :foreground "gray50"
    :box (:line-width 1 :color "black") :weight regular))))
  '(org-warning ((t (:foreground "black"))))
  )
```

Comment: How do I color everything upto org-level-2 and color only the stars from level-3 onwards?

Comment: I think I will have to modify the `org-get-level-face` function from org.el. However I am not that good with elisp yet. Can you please help? I want to color everything until a certain org-level (say level-2) and color only the stars from there onward.

Comment: @Inspired_Blue -- this answer relates to using the variable `org-level-color-stars-only`.  If that solution is insufficient for your particular use-case, then it may behoove you to launch a new question on emacs.stackexchange.com that is narrowly tailored to your particular issue.

Comment: okay - will do that :)